# Add a dot inbetween a string or int to create a double JAVA

Tags: java, regex, string

I need something to turn somthing like this: 29939299322 into 299392.99322 automatically as it has to do this alot.
i have found things like format but it only seems to be able to add things in front of the number but this has to happen after the sixth number.

preferably from an int directly into a double. but i haven't even found a way t do it from a string.

so if any of u know if this is even possible please help me do this.
and it has to be java. if u also know any documentation which can help me also post it,

thanks in advance

Comment: `this has to happen after the sixth number.` So I take 123456789 should be converted to 123456.789? That should be easy: parse the number, divide by `Math.pow(10.0, length - 6)` and reformat back to a string. Or alternatively insert a dot at index 6.

Comment: could you be more precise ? - do you want to add a dot after 6 numbers, in a string ? use substring

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, substring does the job as does the aswer below, thanks for the quick reply, must have been a faulty think way of me to overlook such a simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you are using Strings, you could use regex (Not really efficient but clean and readable:P) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "29939299322";
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("(\\d{6})(\\d+)", "$1.$2"));
}
```

O/P :

```
299392.99322
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,it works pretty well, thanks for that. i will mark the answer a the solution

Comment: @ricardospek - Ywc :)

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int intInput = 123456789; // I am using 123456789 because you want to
                                // input an integer, and "29939299322" is
                                // greater than the maximum value for an
                                // integer: "2147483647"
    String input = intInput + ""; // Converts the input into a String
    String output = ""; // This is the output String, it will later be
                        // converted into a double
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { // Loops through the input
        if (i == input.length() - 5) { // If the index is at the certain
                                        // point in the String...
            output += "."; // Adds "."
        }
        output += input.charAt(i) + ""; // Adds the character into the
                                        // output String after converting it
                                        // into a String
    }
    double outputDouble = Double.parseDouble(output); // Parses the output
                                                        // into a Double
    System.out.println(outputDouble); // Outputs Double
}
```

**Output:**

```
1234.56789
```